# Nested numeration of headings and lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been googling and stackoverflow'ing for quite a long time and I'm stuck.
The task is the following: make nested numbering (`1.`, `1.1.`, `1.1.1` etc.) both for headings (`<h2>` through `<h4>`) and lists (`<ol>` and `<ul>`). The complicating points are:

1. there might be headings and lists in any quantity (for example, one `h2` can have three nested `ol`s, the second `h2` can have two `h3`s, then the first `h3` has two `h4`s, the second of those has `ul` with a nested `ol`, and so on, and so forth). And the numbering should be *unique* and observed across the entire document.
2. the document will be a template for people not soo agile with HTML, so the less classes, data-attributes and so on, the better.

What I've already done:

```
$(function() {
    indices = new Array();
    // Not every element should be numbered, so I've added a class to those who should
    $(".item").each(function() {
        // I'm assigning the level manually, like this:
        // <h4 class="item" data-level="3">blah blah</h4>
        // any better solution is welcome
        var hIndex = parseInt($(this).data("level"));
        if (indices.length - 1 > hIndex) {
            indices= indices.slice(0, hIndex + 1 );
        }
        if (indices[hIndex] == undefined) {
            indices[hIndex] = 0;
        }
        indices[hIndex]++;
        // Now I try to number lists and nested lists, and here I'm stuck
        if ($(this).is("ol, ul")) {
            var $that = $(this);
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {
                // Trying to add those attributes to <li>s... no dice :(
                $(this).addClass("item");
                $(this).data("level", $that.data("level")+1);
            });
        }
        var number = $.grep(indices, Boolean).join(".");
        $(this).prepend(number+". ");
    });
});
```

any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplished it at last, if anyone also does need it like me.
First of all, you need to mark the items (headings and lists) as follows:

```
<h2 class="item" data-level="1">Largest item</h2>
<h3 class="item" data-level="2">A smaller item</h3>
<ol class="item" data-level="3">
<li>Smallest item 1</li>
<li>Smallest item 2</li>
<li>Smallest item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Note: you have to set `data-level` manually, I couldn't do anything with this so far.
And here is the code, put it inside your `$(function() {}`:

```
$("ol.item").each(function() {
    // There might be lots of <li>s, we don't want to set the attributes manually for each one
    $(this).find("li").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("item").data("level", $(this).parent().data("level"));
    });
    $(this).removeClass("item"); // The <ol> does not need this anymore
});

indices = new Array();
$(".item").not("ol").each(function() { // Just in case, we don't need <ol>s
    var hIndex = parseInt($(this).data("level"));
    // Going to the next level
    if (indices.length - 1 > hIndex) {
        indices= indices.slice(0, hIndex + 1 );
    }
    // Going to the previous level
    if (indices[hIndex] == undefined) {
        indices[hIndex] = 0;
    }
    indices[hIndex]++;
    // Cutting off nulls and prepending the number to the item
    $(this).prepend($.grep(indices, Boolean).join(".") + ". ");
});
```